# Bluetooth connection via android

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection

I want to connect my device (HTC Wildfire S) with an OBD2 Dongle.
For that I´ve wrote an Bluetoothprogram based on the Google Developer.
If I try to run the apk on the device, I get an exception witch return false.
So the connection is not running.
Can anybody help me?!
I am new at this forum. Sorry for my English. It´s not my favourit languange =)

In the Manifest I´ve set the Bluetooth and Bluetooth Admin permission.

Here the Source Code from the Main, the Activity and the Manifest.

Main:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    private ConnectedThread connected;
    private boolean isConnected = false;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    //Button ruft die Methode verbindung auf!!!!
    public void verbinden(View view){
        verbindung();
     }


  //Verbindung wird ausgeführt
    private void verbindung(){          //Muss mit Button aufgerufen werden
        String address = "B8:E8:56:41:74:09";       //Adresse vom Dongle
        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        ConnectThread connect = new ConnectThread(device);
        connect.start();
        //connected.write(null);
    }



    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
            // because mmSocket is final
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
                Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
                tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                boolean b = mmSocket.isConnected(); System.out.println(b);
                mmSocket.connect();
                isConnected = true;
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                System.out.println("Ich bin eine Exception.");
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) { }
                return;
            }

            connected = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
            connected.run();
        }

        /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

        private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                    //mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                          //  .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
                connected.write(null);
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.blue_final.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnVerbinden"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="verbinden"
        android:text="verbinden" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/BtnSenden"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/BtnVerbinden"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/BtnVerbinden"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:onClick="senden"
        android:text="Senden" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/TFKonsole"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/BtnSenden"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/BtnVerbinden"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/BtnVerbinden"
        android:layout_below="@+id/BtnVerbinden"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some problems with my OBD II Adapter. He was broken. Now I have a new one.
It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of exception do you get?
Do you get exception when app is starting, or when you press BtnVerbinden?
Also, make sure that Dongle is paired with your Android device.
Pleas give some more detailed information exception you get.

EDIT:

I tried your code.
Basically it is working, i pressed the button and successfully connected to another device.

Comment: Hi, I get an exception if I press BtnVerbinden. In every attempt I ensure, that the Dongle is paired with the device. Tomorrw I can post the LogCat if you want. May it helps.

Comment: Ok. Now I try it with another device. It works. But if I press BtnVerbinden, the connection keep up less then 5 seconds. How can I get a permanent connection?

Comment: Once again, you should add some more info. do you get any exception when connection fails after 5sec? You should use LogCat and DEBUG mode to find errors.
I am using old LG optimus hub with android 2.3.4 with your code, and connection IS permanent.